# Using Rules module to Auto Post the content to Linkedin Account

Tags: 7, social-network

I am using Drupal 7. I used [Feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) module for content from the RSS. So i can get the content from RSS Feeds. Now **Feed** Content types automatically saved with RSS Feeds content. So now I want to auto Post the **Feeds** content to the twitter,linkedin and facebook.I am using [Twitter](https://www.drupal.org/project/twitter) module.

So i can Auto post the content using rules module to Facebook[image: So i can Auto post the content using rules module to Facebook]. 
Same Time I Can Auto Post the content using rules module to twitter.[image: Same Time I Can Auto Post the content using rules module to twitter].
 I want to post this content via rules module to linkedin.. I am using [Linkedin](https://www.drupal.org/project/linkedin) module also. But it doesn't work for rules module ? Using linkein module for particular content types only. I want to post the content for particular user linkedin account?Admin can submit the content post to the linkedin account.But i want to auto post the content for particular user account?

Is there any way to auto post the content via rules module to linkedin account. I am in critical situation.Please anyone guide to me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you tell me how you setup all this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [LinkedIn Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/linkedin)?

> This module provides integration with the LinkedIn API. At the moment
>   it supports the following features:
>
> - Per-user OAuth authentication between LinkedIn and Drupal Post
> - LinkedIn status from node edit form (like the Twitter module)
> - Synchronise LinkedIn user profiles with a user profile tab in Drupal

For Drupal 7 it's still dev and there may or may not be any updates coming. But it would be a good place to start.

Comment: It works perfectly.Same time admin will submit the form.Auto post the content for particular user linkedin account . Is it possible?

Comment: I want to post the content using rules module for After saving new content.So I want to Post the content to linkedin. I am using linkedin module. But it doesn't show the rules module

Answer (score 1):

This module does't have this functionality. You need your own rules action or use php with rules (Using embed php with rules isn't the best practice). I did some digging and found proper function to run. linkedin_status_set_status($status, $node);
This is function from linkedin_status module.
I have not tested it anyhow but I am 99% sure this should work.
Create new module and add

```
function YOURMODULE_rules_action_info() {
  return array(
    'YOURMODULE_set_inkedin_status' => array(
      'label' => t('Set linkedin status'), 
      'parameter' => array(
        'node' => array(
          'type' => 'node',
          'label' => t('Node'),
        ),
        'status' => array(
          'type' => 'text',
          'label' => t('Status'),
        ),
      ), 
      'group' => t('Linkedin'), 
    ),
  );
}
function YOURMODULE_set_inkedin_status($status, node) {
   linkedin_status_set_status($status, $node);
}
```